# Trying to make nav text change color when hovering over the button and not only the text

Tags: html, css, nav, sidebar

I made a nav with padding on each side and a background color. I have a default color on the text and made the background turn another color when hovered. The issue is that i want the text to change color when the background is hovered and not the text only because i need to use the same color as the default text for the background color[when hovered] right now if i hover then it will basically be invisible text since the background and text will be the same color. I want the text color to change even when hovering the space outside the text and not the text exclusively.

jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ucsk99cL/

```
<aside class="sidebar">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li style=""><a href="">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">about us</a></li>
            <li><a href="">orders</a></li>
            <li><a href="">gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</aside>




.sidebar{
float:left;
margin:20px;
margin-right:150px;
}

nav ul li a{
text-decoration:none;
font-family:myriad pro;
font-size:20px;
color:#3d2316;
}


nav ul li{
padding-top:26px;
padding-bottom:26px;
padding-left:57px;
padding-right:57px;
margin-bottom:3px;
background-color: #CBAFA2;
}

nav ul li:hover{
background-color: #3D2316;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the color when hovering over the parent, `li` element:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/9f5k2ne4/)

```
nav ul li:hover a {
    color: #fff;
}
```

And if you want to be able to click anywhere within the `li`, you would have to add the padding to the anchor elements as opposed to the `li` elements. Just change the `display` to `inline-block` so that it respects the padding. I also made a few other changes, see the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/9f5k2ne4/).

```
nav ul li a {
    padding:26px 58px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<aside class="sidebar">
<nav>
    <ul>

        <li id="test"><a href="">home</a></li>
        <li id="test"><a href="">about us</a></li>
        <li id="test"><a href="">orders</a></li>
        <li id="test"><a href="">gallery</a></li>
        <li id="test"><a href="">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Add the following css code;

```
#test:hover a {color:red;}
```